# Terraform - Load IP lists in JSON to Terraform

Tags: terraform

I need help loading IP lists into JSON via terraform.

My structure of files are:

---------**Project Folder**

---main.tf

--------**firewall-ip-list**

---------iplist1.txt

---------iplist2.txt

----------**assets**

------config.json

In my main.tf i'm using Akamai_property_rules_template module to load Akamai JSON configuration in terraform:

```
data "akamai_property_rules_template" "rules" {
  template_file = abspath("${path.module}/assets/config.json")

  variables {
    name = "iplist1"
    value = file("firewall-ip-list/iplist1.txt")
    type = "string"
  }

  variables {
  name = "iplist2"
  value = file("firewall-ip-list/iplist2.txt")
  type = "string"
}
```

My iplists has this formats:

```
"186.100.200.10/32",
"186.100.200.11/32",
```

And my JSON configuration have these format

```
"criteria": [
    {
      "name": "clientIp",
      "options": {
        "matchOperator": "IS_NOT_ONE_OF",
        "useHeaders": false,
        "values": [
          "{env.vpn_iplist1}"
       
      ]
```

If run a terraform plan and Apply it works, but if i use more than one list in JSON file

```
{
      "name": "clientIp",
      "options": {
        "matchOperator": "IS_NOT_ONE_OF",
        "useHeaders": false,
        "values": [
          "${env.vpn_iplist1}"
          "${env.iplist2}"
       
      ]
      }
```

Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan

│ Error: invalid JSON result: invalid character '1' after array element

There's another way to do this or solve the issue?

Load more than 1 List of IPs to apply in terraform to Akamai property configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really difficult question to understand, if I'm interpreting it correctly, the `variable` blocks you are supplying are passed into your config as the `${env._}` variables?

If that's the case, then your problem is probably your final `iplist2` variable, because there's a trailing comma, which means your config would be:

```
{
      "name": "clientIp",
      "options": {
        "matchOperator": "IS_NOT_ONE_OF",
        "useHeaders": false,
        "values": [
          "186.100.200.10/32",
          "186.100.200.11/32",
          "186.100.200.10/32",
          "186.100.200.11/32",
        ]
}
```

Which lines up with your error `invalid character '1' after array element`

Answer (score 0):

it worked by this way:

In JSON file i've declared the iplists:

```
 "values": [
          ${env.iplist1},
          ${env.iplist2},
          ${iplist3},
          ${iplist14}
        ]
```

And in IP lists i removed the comma (,) in the last line

```
"186.100.200.10/32",
"186.100.200.11/32",
"186.100.200.10/32",
"186.100.200.11/32" <---- comma removed in last line of all ip lists file.
```

This solve the issue, and the configurations has been applied